# What does v.distance calculate exactly?

Tags: qgis, polygon, grass-gis, distance

As I am from an economics department, I am quite a beginner in QGIS. 
I read, that if I wanted to calculate the distance from a polygon to a point/line/another polygon, I should use the GRASS plugin `v.distance`.

Does anyone know how exactly the plugin calculates the distance? Let's say I want to know what's the minimum distance from Bavaria to the sea. Does `v.distance` take the center of Bavaria or does it divide the border into small points and then calculate the distance to the nearest sea spot?

Comment: Please explain "Minimum distance from Germany to the sea" ... it is 0m since Germany is at the sea :-) If you want to calculate the distance between *centroid* of the Germanyy polygon and the coastline, then it differs from the question "what is the minimal distance between two polygons". Please consider to edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markus Metz, one of the GRASS developers, described in one of his [posts](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/v-distance-anything-to-anything-td5008416.html) how such features are calculated.

Here is the quote:

> **For lines to lines**, say line A to line B, it calculates shortest
>   distance of each vertex in A with each segment (not vertex) in B. So
>   far, this is the same like in the original version, results are
>   identical. Now if line A is a line or boundary, it calculates the
>   shortest distance of each vertex in B to each segment in A.
>   Additionally, it checks for intersections. In case of intersections,
>   the first intersection found is used and the distance set to zero.
>
> **For lines to areas**, it behaves similar to the original version. If a
>   line is inside an area, the distance is set to zero. The first point
>   of the line inside the area is used as common point. The distance is
>   also set to zero if the line intersects with the outer ring or any of
>   the inner rings (isles), in which case the fist intersection is used
>   as common point.
>
> **For areas to areas**, the module checks first for overlap or if one area
>   is (partially) inside the other area. This is computationally quite
>   intensive. If the outer rings of the two areas do not overlap, the
>   distance is calculated as above for lines to lines, treating the outer
>   rings as two lines. Again, the first point encountered falling into an
>   area is used as common point, or the first intersection point.
>
> **For anything else than points to lines**, there can be several common
>   points with distance = zero, and the closest location could then be
>   several points or several lines or several areas (result of overlay).
>   For v.distance, I choose to select a single point, and not create an
>   overlay like v.overlay.

Hope this clears it up a little!