# Distance to Nearest Hub QGIS not working when 'hub' is a line?

Tags: qgis, vector, distance

***QGIS 2.18.20 working in CRS: WGS 84/UTM Zone 35S (EPSG:32735 OTF), with shapefiles of map features (roads, river, point water sources) reprojected from WGS84 EPSG:4326.***

All shapefiles have been reprojected (in order to be ***able to work in metres*** not degrees). Map features originally from GPS source, input to qgis using lat/long coordinates.

I'm trying to run Distance To Nearest Hub analysis for animal sightings (300+ points in one layer) to the various features in my map (see list above). The analysis works well for the point data (e.g. Source= sighting point, Hub= water source point) but not for the line files (road, river, fence).

For the lines, it just seems to choose a central point to that feature and calculate the distance to that one point from the source (sighting) points (see screenshot)[image].

I've tried adding geom info to the line shapefiles but they just add in length and the 'Distance to nearest Hub' analysis ends the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Using `Distance to Nearest Hub` tool, I reproduced the same situation as you have posted.

[image]

My suggestion is to use a GRASS tool `v.distance` which can be found under ( *Processing Toolbox | GRASS GIS 7 | Vector* ).

`From` is your animal siting points and `To` is the line layer such as the rivers.

[image]

To be honest, using `v.distance` through QGIS processing toolbox is still tricky and challenging. (You may encounter errors by running it in default setting). My workaround is to remove `cat` in the `'upload'` field and leave it blank.

[image]

As you can imagine, this does not give you the distance of each line. To obtain the distance from each animal observation to the nearby river, open the attribute table of *Distance* (output by `v.distance`) and use the Field calculator to calculate `$length`.

Comment: [@kazuhito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84455/kazuhito), good job! I just want to attach a useful article [Get nearest line to point with v.distance in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263508/get-nearest-line-to-point-with-v-distance-in-qgis). The background of `v.distance` could be examined in this article [What does v.distance calculate excactly?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163432/what-does-v-distance-calculate-excactly)